# count records from a table all the time whenever a select query is performed

Tags: plsql, count

i want to count all the records in a table whenever a select query is performed in schema.

each time i cannot write select count(*) from (select_query).
i want a utility,procedure,func etc which counts the records in table
note: I use SQL devloper tool.

Answer (score 0):

the query seems particularly strange. This can really cripple your database. (Depending on the optimizer mode and usage level of the database, this will "kill" it).

The only way I see is to use fine grained audit (DBMS_FGA) [as explained here](http://technology.amis.nl/2005/09/26/select-trigger-in-oracle-database-introducing-fine-grained-auditing/).

It should be easy from the example to add something like

```
select_sql := sys_context('userenv','current_sql');   
if instr(select_sql, 'select /*counter*/ count(*)') = 0 then
      nb_rows := execute immediate('select /*counter*/ count(*) from (' || select_sql || ')'); 
end if;
```

and store the result in a dedicated table or send somewhere else.

Of course you shall generate one trigger per table.